# A life copy of a file in the same computer

Tags: macos, backup

Is it possible to have a live copy of a folder in another place of the same computer?

Why do I need that? I use an online back up program "Backblaze" It does not back up the Applications folder. I use Mamp to work php local. Files and databases are stored in my mac: Applications/Mamp. So I need to have a copy of htdocs file (where are the files) and db (where are the databases) anywhere outside of the Applications, to be save. So I am looking for a way to have a folder outside the Applications that automatically makes a copy of that files inside Applications/Mamp. I'll will be open too, to any other way to have a safe copy of my work in php.

Comment: Will shortcuts work?

Comment: @Robuust: what do you mean? I do not understand

Comment: Take a look at "continuous backup" software, sometimes also called "real-time backup". Alternatively, you can set a cronjob to rsync your backup folder to your work folder every minute. Not quite "live", but close enough for practical purposes. Thirdly, you can turn your work folder into a git repo (with the actual repo located outside of the Applications folder) and then have a cronjob do `git commit -am 'foo'` every minute. This will give you a by-minute archive of *all* past versions of your work files.